# addEventListener in for loop adds always to last item

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener

I'm currently writing a chrome extension, so don't mind the "chrome.*" code.

Right now, I'm facing a problem and I have no idea how to solve this (tried everything I could find on google)..

This is my function:

```
function tabwlwatchlist() {  
document.getElementById('watchlisttable').innerHTML = "";
chrome.storage.local.get('movienames', function (resultnames) {
    chrome.storage.local.get('movielinks', function (resultlinks) {
        for (var j=0; j<resultnames.movienames.length; j++) {
            (function () {
            document.getElementById('watchlisttable').innerHTML += '<tr><td><h3 class="article_preview"><a href="' + resultlinks.movielinks[j] + '" target="_blank"><span>' + resultnames.movienames[j] + '</span></a></h3></td><td><h3 class="article_preview"><span id="wlt' + j +'">entfernen</span></h3></td></tr>'; 
            console.log("test");
            document.getElementById('wlt' + j).addEventListener("click", function(){
                alert('works');
            }, false);
            console.log("test2");
        }())
        }
    });
});
document.getElementById('lasthd').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('lastserien').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('watchlisttab').style.display = "block";
}
```

The EventListener always adds to the last Element of the for loop.

Any ideas? :/

Comment: JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Using *innerHTML* to modify table elements will fail in most (all?) versions of IE, see [*MSDN*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

your j value has became the height number after the for loop is executed....to solve it you have to know  a common javascript phenomenon called closure.To prevent this you have to provide the argument `j` to the immediately invoked function.You can learn more about them [enter link description here](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

```
function tabwlwatchlist() {  
document.getElementById('watchlisttable').innerHTML = "";
chrome.storage.local.get('movienames', function (resultnames) {
    chrome.storage.local.get('movielinks', function (resultlinks) {
        for (var j=0; j<resultnames.movienames.length; j++) {
            (function (j) {
            document.getElementById('watchlisttable').innerHTML += '<tr><td><h3 class="article_preview"><a href="' + resultlinks.movielinks[j] + '" target="_blank"><span>' + resultnames.movienames[j] + '</span></a></h3></td><td><h3 class="article_preview"><span id="wlt' + j +'">entfernen</span></h3></td></tr>'; 
            console.log("test");
            document.getElementById('wlt' + j).addEventListener("click", function(){
                alert('works');
            }, false);
            console.log("test2");
        }(j))
        }
    });
});
document.getElementById('lasthd').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('lastserien').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('watchlisttab').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: thanks, i already managed it by adding a second for loop because the "innerHTML" always overwrote my EventListener ;)